# Observer for monitoring when view controllers' viewDidAppear have been executed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

### Summary of question

UINavigationControllerDelegate:didShowViewContoller makes it possible to get notified whenever any view controller has been displayed (as opposed to being loaded), provided its within the context of a navigation stack.
I want to know if such observation is possible for all view controllers if there isn't a navigation stack.

### More background

I have an app where view controllers can suddenly appear based upon timers and local notifications firing, thus their appearance is effectively random.

If one VC triggers and gets displayed at the same time as another was in the process of getting displayed then there can be an issue (if you're experienced with iOS you'll be aware if one VC pushes another from within its viewDidLoad, rather than its viewDidAppear you will get an "attempting to present X on Y whose view is not in the window hierarchy" error)

How I solve this is I have a list of VCs to display and they get displayed by a view controller co-ordinator which implements UINavigationControllerDelegate's didShowViewContoller and doesn't display the new VC until didShowViewController has been invoked.

This works perfectly.

But now my problem is I want to do a similar thing for an app that isn't using a navigation controller, and thus I can't use UINavigationControllerDelegate:didShowViewController to observe globally when a view controller has been displayed. Does anybody know of another elegant mechanism for doing so?

Comment: What about posting an `NSNotification` from viewDidAppear.  You could create a UIViewController subclass with the necessary code in that method, and subclass that for all your VCs.

Comment: This will get packaged as a library for inclusion into another app, and I wan't to avoid having to make changes to existing view controller's in that other app (but maybe that's still possible using a swizzle or something)

Comment: @MartinH Have you tried anything with forward invocation in order to solve this where you send a message to an object but wrap up in that message another "selector", let's say, that's actually part of another object's method entirely? Quick note, I'm not talking about swizzling, this has nothing to do with swizzling.

Comment: Larcerax, could you please provide a few more details what you are thinking

Comment: A solution I'm going to explore to see if its feasible is to: 1) get the current top view controller 2) if the vc.view.window is nil then its not finished displaying, 3) dynamically add KVO to the vc.view.window 4) when the KVO triggers display the new VC 5) remove the KVO