# How to dismiss a ViewController reliably, even if animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

We are building a data acquisition app that allows the user to enter other view controllers (preferences screen, log screen) brought forth by

```
[self presentViewController:secondary_view animated:YES completion: nil].
```

When certain data arrives, we want to shut down all of these secondary views summarily.  We are using

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion: nil];
```

to do this. What we find, though, is that if the data comes in *while* the new view is sliding into place (not done animating), then the dismiss command has no effect, and the secondary view is still there, and in fact the app gets confused about its own state in a way that makes it appear to "hang."

Is there a better (more reliable) way to make sure that all presented view controllers are dismissed, even if they are currently animating?

Comment: Sounds like the `isBeingPresented` and `isBeingDismissed` methods of `UIViewController` are exactly what you need to solve your problem. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isBeingPresented

Comment: You can use 'self.presentedViewController' to get the current modal view controller and check if you should dismiss it. Maybe that helps

Comment: You don't have multiple secondary views open at once, do you?

Comment: this is along the same lines as what you are dealing with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215180/observer-for-monitoring-when-view-controllers-viewdidappear-have-been-executed#comment52315562_32215180

Comment: the hardest thing to manage, is this ... you can definately time the controllers correctly to dismiss ad not overlap and such and wait for aniamtion to complete, the easy way to do this is subclass a UINavigationController and then work with the animators in this subclass to lock down transitions and only allow one completion at a time. The difficulty will come later when the UI is more advanced and then you'd have to turn to objective-c run time libraries.

Comment: here's an example of what your subclass will sort of need to look like, this is a simple implementation:https://github.com/nzeltzer/LBXCompletingNavigationController/blob/master/LBXNavigationController/LBXCompletingNavigationController.m

Comment: You can check isBeingPresented/dismissed and use transitionCoordinator to schedule some block to perform upon transition completion. In a more reliable scenario I would suggest to implement informal protocol and let controllers report as soon as they get available. Events can be polled and fired as soon as one of top controllers settles down.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to present the scene using `Interface Builder` (storyboards) and set the `Segue Identifier` to a certain string with the type of presenting you're wanting done: `show`, `show detail`, `modally` or `popover`.

*(see below)*

[image]

Once you've done this, you can use the method: `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier`, where you can be assured the data exchange between the `segue.destinationViewController`, the View Controller you're sending the data too, and the current View Controller is performed.

*(see below)*

[image]

**NOTE**

You can perform a segue programmatically using `performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:`

Also, be sure to remove all the strong references to the data objects that are not being released in your current scenario. Try doing this within the Method above after you've transferred the data to the destination View Controller.